# PHP File Exists returns false; when the file does actually exist

Tags: php

The strangest thing happened to me, I was developing a simple file upload script, and it worked, but then it stopped working?
So I have troubleshooted and isolated the problem to the fact that the server is not accepting the fact that a specific folder actually exists.  The basic gist of the code is shown below (please forgive the messiness of the code, it is just a rough draft at this point...):

BASIC FILE CREATION:

```
 $date = date("y-m-d");
    $category = "tech";    
    $url_m = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. "/" . $category . "/articles/" . $date . "/images/";
        if(!file_exists($url_m)){
            mkdir($url_m, 0777, true);
            $segment = "/" . $category . "/articles/" . $date . "/";
        }
        else{
            for($i = 1; $i <= 100; $i++){
                $url_new = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. "/" . $category . "/articles/" . $date . "-" . $i . "/images/";
                $segment = "/" . $category . "/articles/" . $date . "-" . $i . "/";
                if(!file_exists($url_new)){
                    echo $segment;
                    $url_m = $url_new;
                    mkdir($url_m, 0777, true);
                    echo $url_m;
                    break;
                }
                else{
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
        $name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
        $url = "http://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $segment;
        $upload_url = str_replace("/images/", "", $url_m); 
        $pic_url = uploadFile($segment, $name, $_FILES['file']['type']); 

Now the UPLOAD script

function uploadFile($dir, $name, $type){
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

        $allowed =  array('gif','png','jpg','JPG','jpeg');
        $filename = $name;
        $ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        if(!in_array($ext,$allowed) ) {
            echo 'error';
        }    

        $tmp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $error = $_FILES['file']['error'];

        if (isset ($name)) {
            if (!empty($name)) {

            $location ="<br>". $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$dir. "images/";
                echo $location. "<br>";
                if(!file_exists($location)){echo "no";}
if (!is_writeable($location.$name)) {
   die("Cannot write to destination file");
}
            if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $location.$name)){
                $path  = "http://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $dir ."/images/". $name;
                return $path;
                }
                else { return "WRONG";}
                } else {
                  echo 'please choose a file';
                  }
            }
        }
        else{return 0;}
    }
```

As always, please know that I would not be asking this question if I hadn't already struggled with it for hours first and all help is very much appreciated!

**EDIT:**
Here is the HTML CODE for the form:

```
<form method="post" action="../site-resources/db-config/db-post.php" enctype= "multipart/form-data"> 
News Category: 
    <select name = "category" id = "category" required>
       ...
    </select><br>
Subcategory: 
    <select name = "subcategory" required >
        ...
    </select>
    <br>
Article Title: <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Article Title" required /><br>
Article Subtitle: <input type="text" name="subtitle" placeholder="Article Subtitle" required /><br>
Author's Name: <input type="text" name="author_name" placeholder="Author Name" required /><br>
Upload Image for Article: <input type = "file" name = "file" id = "image"><br>
    Main Text:<br><textarea cols = "100" rows = "30" name = "article_body">Article Body Goes Here</textarea>
<br><br>
<h4>Security Question: Please Enter your Editor Code to post to this website</h4>
<input type = "text" name = "security_question" placeholder="Security Question" required />

<input type="submit" name = "submit" value="Post Article" />
```

Comment: If `file_exists()` says that a file does not exist then it almost certainly does not exist. Get the full path from the OS, print out the path in your script, and compare them character for character.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen Yes, I realize that.  I compared the two strings and they are exactly the same.  One from my Explorer and one echoed from PHP.  It is really freaky...

Comment: Should also make sure the file permissions are not messed up. Recently had PHP create a file with 000 permissions.

Comment: I tried checking the permissions and they are in fact 0777 (I made them 0777 as a stop gap measure to fix the problem).  The funny part is when I use a separate php file to test "file_exists()" on the same exact path, it comes up as "existing."  So basically. there is some problem with my current code that is preventing the folder from being seen as existing? (sorry if that make no sense)

Comment: Actually, I think the error might lie with php.ini, the file that I was attempting to upload was 4 M and the file upload cap was 1 M (weird..), anyway, I'm going to test it further to confirm a solution

Answer (score 0):

Don't know whether this is the actual proble. So Need to see the HTML form, usually most forget to write enctype.

Add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to form to enable upload of files

```
<form id="someform"  action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: Thanks, but i did include the enctype

Comment: @Ignatius_Gim  show me the complete error code.plus  html form would be better

Comment: No PHP error code is being shown, even with error reporting on

Answer (score 0):

This works! Tested

```
$date = date("y-m-d");
    $category = "tech";    
    $url_m = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $category . "/articles/" . $date . "/images/";
        if(!file_exists($url_m)){
            mkdir($url_m, 0777, true);
            $segment = $category . "/articles/" . $date . "/";
        }
        else{
            for($i = 1; $i <= 100; $i++){
                $url_new = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $category . "/articles/" . $date . "-" . $i . "/images/";
                $segment = $category . "/articles/" . $date . "-" . $i . "/";
                if(!file_exists($url_new)){
                   echo $segment;
                    $url_m = $url_new;
                    mkdir($url_m, 0777, true);
                    echo $url_m;
                    break;
                }
                else{
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
        $name=isset($_FILES['file']['name'])?$_FILES['file']['name']:"";
        $type=isset($_FILES['file']['type'])?$_FILES['file']['type']:"";
        $url = "http://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $segment;
        $upload_url = str_replace("/images/", "", $url_m); 
        $pic_url = uploadFile($segment, $name, $type); 

//Now the UPLOAD script

function uploadFile($dir, $name, $type){
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

        $allowed =  array('gif','png','jpg','jpeg');
        $filename = $name;
        $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
        echo $ext;
        if(!in_array($ext,$allowed) ) {
            echo 'error';
        }    

        $tmp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $error = $_FILES['file']['error'];

        if (isset ($name)) {
            if (!empty($name)) {

            $location =$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$dir. "images/";
                echo "location:".$location. "<br>";

               if(file_exists($location.$name))
               {
                   echo "file exists";
                   if(!is_writeable($location.$name)) {
                   die("Cannot write to destination file. its not writable");
                   }
               }
               else
               {
                   echo "file doesn't exist";
                }
            if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $location.$name)){
                $path  = "http://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $dir ."/images/". $name;
                echo "file moved";
                return $path;
                }
                else { return "WRONG";}
                } else {
                  echo 'please choose a file';
                  }
            }
        }
        else{return 0;}
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunatey it does not for me, it still cannot "locate" the directory, returning "file does not exist"